# Create free app - but only for users who already bought a paid version?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, google-play

I would like to create a free give-away app for everyone who bought my app in Android market or on Apple app store.

Is there a way to create a different app and make it only available for free to all those who already bought another app? It's not an add-on to the paid version - it's a separate app.

Thanks

Comment: It is dirty but you can host the apk somewhere and put a link to the apk in your paid apps (as an update). Anyway there is certainly a more elegant and secure way to do it through the market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like that,
if someone bought your paid application then give him token like key and if he want to use free application then he need to enter a token to access that application in the starting of application then authenticate him either by using local database base or Webservice

Comment: To be more specific than what AndroidDeveloper said: have a hash function in your paid program that uses as a key something the user provides. Have them enter the hash value and their private key in the free program, which only unlocks if the hash value provided is correct.

Comment: I am nut sure I understand completely - the user of the paid app would provide a key to get a hash value? What key? I understand that the paid app would generate a valid key just by itself which then can be used in the free app. But I think you meant something different - could you please explain. Thanks

Comment: Take a number may be 15 digit number if user installed paid version he will got this number.And now save this number in local DB of free application if user open this free application after installing app then fetch number stored in local DB and compare both if both are eqaul then set flag for next time and now user can use it easily

Comment: Hope you Got this time else come to chat

Comment: yes, thanks I get it. Just one more - do you see any practical way so that 15digit number cannot just be posted anywhere on the internet and then anybody else can use it? ps I wonder if an app like that would be accepted by Apple - Android I think is OK -> I started a chat just to be sure...

Comment: let me know ,,do you have webservice to obtain this purpose?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4611/discussion-between-androiddeveloper-and-user387184)

Answer (score 0):

Apple currently has no provision for this kind of set up. The only work-arounds i can think of would be very restrictive (e.g. implementing a user system in the two apps) and may not pass Apple's guidelines as it maybe classified as limiting user functionality. Others may have more knowledge on these guidelines.